# how to get/set values for a nested data object javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I originally had my game and key objects exposed as a global variable. I decided to do a closure so I can hide the win key and only expose the data when called for.

I'm not sure how to get/set the values properly. I think I need to define routes to the object but the way I'm thinking involves making a get/set function for every property I need to access, and I find this very ugly. You can see this in the setStatus() I was trying to make.

My JavaScript is a bit basic at the moment, so if you have any suggestions on making the code better, please let me know!

**Updated Code**
For my setStatus, I want to be able to have this one function update the appropriate key:value in status, but I'm not sure how to do it elegantly. Currently I have it as checking for a string value of "moveNumber" or "movePool". If I do it this way, then when I make a setPlayers function, I'll have to check for a p1/p2 and check the key as well. There should be a better way.

```
var data = (function() {
    var game = {
        status: {
            "moveNumber": 1,
            "movePool": []
        },
        players: { 
            p1: {
                "title": "Player 1",
                "moves": [],
                "marker": "#17C000"
            },
            p2: {
                "title": "Player 2",
                "moves": [],
                "marker": "#E60000"
            }
        }
    };
    var key = {
        win: {
            "winSet": ["abc","def","ghi","adg","beh","cfi","aei","gec"]
        },
    };
    return {
        getGame: function() {
            return game.players;
        },
        getStatus: function() {
            return game.status;
        },
        getWin: function() {
            return key.win;
        },
        setStatus: function(route, val) {
            if (route === "moveNumber") {
                game.status.moveNumber = val;
            }
            else if (route === "movePool") {
                game.status.movePool = val;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

**Original Code Post**

```
var data = (function() {
    var game = {
        players: { 
            status: {
                "moveNumber": 1,
                "movePool": []
            },
            p1: {
                "title": "Player 1",
                "moves": [],
                "marker": "#17C000"
            },
            p2: {
                "title": "Player 2",
                "moves": [],
                "marker": "#E60000"
            }
        }
    };
    var key = {
        win: {
            "winSet": ["abc","def","ghi","adg","beh","cfi","aei","gec"]
        },
    };
    return {
        getGame: function() {
            return game.players;
        },
        getWin: function() {
            return key.win;
        },
        setStatus: function(route, val) {
            if (route == status) {
                return this.game.players.status
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: I could not catch your idea, on a set call you actually do get, returning data

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Your `setStatus` isn't setting anything, it's returning a value (aka *getting*). And why would you need to pass it a `route` anyway?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Updated my original post.